# How to reference an aliased column in where clause that contains a grouping function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple sql query below, which produces a usable result for me. However I would ideally like to further limit the results of this query to only include results where the aliased column total is less then 10.  I have tried directly referencing the aliased column in  a where clause, and also duplicating the COUNT() portion in a where clause, but that doesn't work. Here is the query, thanks in advance for the help.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT iDomainID) AS totInFile, iFileGroup
FROM Domains.`ApacheVirtualHosts`
GROUP BY iFileGroup
```

Comment: Not tried this, but it sounds like you need the HAVING clause. Something like GROUP BY iFileGroup HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT iDomainID) < 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can further filter using a [HAVING](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php) clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT iDomainID) AS totInFile, iFileGroup
FROM Domains.`ApacheVirtualHosts`
GROUP BY iFileGroup
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT iDomainID) < 10;
```

A HAVING clause will allow you to filter data using an aggregate function.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I appreciate that, I will accept your answer when the time limit is up.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT iDomainID) AS totInFile, iFileGroup
FROM Domains.`ApacheVirtualHosts`
GROUP BY iFileGroup
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT iDomainID) < 10
```